# Infinite login redirect loop with Google and ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, google-oauth, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-authorization

I've hit a redirect loop when trying to access a page behind an Authorize attribute in Net Core 3 no matter whether I am signed in or if the user has permissions. I've followed the MSDN tutorials and done some searching but have yet to find a solution to my issue. I suspect that it isn't recognizing my identity cookie or somehow it isn't redirecting to the right page but I need some guidance on what to look for.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<GuitarCatalogMVCContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite( Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddIdentity<GuitarCatalogAuthUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<GuitarCatalogMVCContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google");
            });

            services.AddAuthorization();
        }

     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

Using the Google login at `/Identity/Account/Login`, I get the proper prompt, I can successfully login, and the url is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount? 
response_type=code &client_id= ______ 
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44346%2Fsignin-google 
&scope=openid%20profile%20email &state= _______ &flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

When I open a controller method behind an `[Authorize]` attribute, 
via `<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Listings")" target="_blank"><h1>TEST CREATE LISTING</h1></a>`, it signs me in and then brings me immediately back to the same page

I opened the Network tab in Dev Tools and here I can see where my sign in was processed, it took me to the Create page, and then I ended up back at the sign in page. I don't see anything that shows that my sign in failed (or why it is prompting me again to sign in when I am signed in).

[image]

Comment: which msdn tutorial are you following.  I tried this as well with the google .net client library and had a similar result.

Comment: I ran into such an issue a couple years ago and it was because my browser wasn't setting cookies properly. It didn't like setting cookies during a server-side redirect, so I had to do the redirect client-side with a small timed delay.

Comment: @DaImTo I am using this one, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: are you just trying to authenticate with google not access the apis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is in the middleware execution order.

`app.UseAuthorization()`  should be executed **after** `app.UseAuthentication()`

In your current implementation since the authorization middleware is executed first, the User object is never set and therefore all requests appear to be unauthorized.

Comment: That solves the problem of being unable to access an endpoint behind [Authorize] when I am signed in as a user with permissions but when I am not I end up with the same login loop even when selecting the proper credentials. I have to log in and then hit the link